# How do I get to my spinnaker dashboard after Installing minnaker on my aws ec2

Tags: spinnaker

I installed spinnaker on my AWS EC2, login into the dashboard in the first time but immediately after I logout and login again using the same base URL i am being directed to a different person github account, what might have happened, does it mean my account is hacked or what, somebody advise please.
Being directed to the link attached below, instead of the ip address taking me to the spinnaker dashboard and yet I am using the correct base address

Comment: If you think you've been compromised, please do not post the potentially compromised URL

Comment: Incase it is compromised does it mean I terminate the whole ec2 or what is your opinion @mokugo-devops

Comment: If you believe its been compromised shut the instance down, take a snapshot and launch it in another VPC that is not connected to any other infrastructure. From there investigate, but be careful about how you do it

Comment: okay, I will do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the instructions i follow for Minnaker on EC2 (ap-southeast-2)
Pre-requisites

- Obtain an AWS Elastic IP
- From AWS EC2 console choose a Region preferably ap-southeast-2 and
  launch an EC2 instance with 16 GB memory, 4 cpu min and 60 GB disk.
  An initial deployment can be performed using instance= m4.xlarge
- Attach the AWS Elastic IP to the Spinnaker Instance
- Access  the instance through SSH

**Get minnaker**
`curl -LO https://github.com/armory/minnaker/releases/latest/download/minnaker.tgz`

Untar
`tar -xzvf minnaker.tgz`

Go to minnaker directory
`cd minnaker`

Use the Public IP value from The Elastic IP as the $PUBLIC_IP
Obtain Private IP of the instance hostname -I and add them to local environment variables $PRIVATE_IP
`export PRIVATE_IP=$(hostname -I)`
`export PUBLIC_IP=AWS_ELASTIC_IP`

Execute the command below to install Open Source Spinnaker
`./scripts/install.sh -o -P $PRIVATE_IP`

**Validate installation**

**UI**

Validate installation going to generated URL `https://PUBLIC_IP`

Use user admin and get the password at  `etc/spinnaker/.hal/.secret/spinnaker_password`

The UI should load

**Kubernetes Deployment**

Minnaker is deployed inside an EC2 as a lightweight Kubernetes K3S cluster

Run `kubectl version`

Get info from cluster `kubectl cluster-info`

Tweak bash completion and enable a simple alias.

`kubectl completion bash`
`kubectl completion bash`
`echo 'source <(kubectl completion bash)' >>~/.bashrc`
`kubectl completion bash >/etc/bash_completion.d/kubectl`
`echo 'alias k=kubectl' >>~/.bashrc`
`echo 'complete -F __start_kubectl k' >>~/.bashrc

**Validate Spinnaker is running**

`k -n spinnaker get pods -o wide`

**Halyard Config**

Validate a default halyard config is been set up

`sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/hal`
`#!/bin/bash`
`set -x`
`HALYARD=$(kubectl -n spinnaker get pod -l app=halyard -oname | cut -d'/' -f 2)`
`k -n spinnaker exec -it ${HAYLYARD} -- hal $@ config`

**Minnaker repo**

Clone the repository 
Go to Scripts directory cd minnaker/scripts
Add permissions to the installation script chmod 775 all.sh
`git clone https://github.com/armory/minnaker`

**References**
[armory/minnaker](https://github.com/armory/minnaker)

Comment: I followed the above steps and managed to install spinnaker in my AWS ec2, the challenge I have it is like my IP address was allocated to a different, so when I try to load the minnaker UI using the allocated base url or the public DNS of my ec2, I am directed to a different UI of somebodys Github page

Comment: I followed the above steps and managed to install spinnaker in my AWS ec2, the challenge I have it is like my IP address was allocated to a different, so when I try to load the minnaker UI using the allocated base url or the public DNS of my ec2, I am directed to a different UI of somebodys Github page

Comment: @MokiDaniel thats odd. Try using a totally new EC2 instance with an attached Elastic IP in a different region. Also get the minnaker package latest or even try with an older version. I am not sure exactly what you are doing to get that github page. 
i install minnaker instances often in Sydney region and i have never come across this one!